# Forecasting an MA(1) process

Tags: time-series, self-study

Suppose $x_{t} = w_{t} + \theta w_{t-1}$ where $w_t$ is white noise with variance $\sigma_{w}^2$

Derive the minimum mean square error one-step forecast based on the infinite past and determine the mean square error of this forecast.

Let $\tilde{x}_n^{n+1}$ be the truncated one step ahead forecast based on the n previous observations. Show that $E[(x_{n+1}-\tilde{x}_n^{n+1})^2=$ $\sigma_w^2(1+\theta^{(2+2n)})$

The solution for the first part states that:
$x_{n+1} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}-\theta^{j}x_{n+1-j} + w_{n+1}$ and $\tilde{x}_{n+1}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-(\theta)^{j}x_{n+1-j})$ so the $MSE = E[x_{n+1}-\tilde{x}_{n+1}] = \sigma_{w}^2$. I am not sure how the expression for $x_{n+1}$ or $\tilde{x}_{n}^{n+1}$ was arrived at. Can someone explain how this was derived? I know $x_{n+1}$ is a linear process but I am not sure where the $-\theta$ plays a role.

For the second part, the solution states $\tilde{x}_{n}^{n+1}= \sum_{j=1}^{n}-\theta^{j}x_{n+1-j}$ and $MSE = E(x_{n+1} - \tilde{x}_{n}^{n+1})^2 =E[\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}-\theta^{j}x_{n+1-j} + w_{n+1}]^2$. I am not sure how this was arrived at.

Answer (score 1):

The MA(1) model $x_t = w_t + \theta w_{t-1}\,$ can be written as
$$
    x_t = \left(1 + \theta L\right) w_t \, . 
$$

Hence
$$
    \left(1 + \theta L\right)^{-1}x_t =  w_t \, . 
$$

Expand, let $t = n+1$, put everything but $x_{n+1}$ on the RHS.

Then, for the next part, take expectations of both sides.

The last part doesn't look right. It's correct to here:

$$
MSE = E(x_{n+1} - \tilde{x}_{n}^{n+1})^2
$$

But then using your earlier mathematics, $x_{n+1} - \tilde{x}_{n}^{n+1}$ should just be $w_{n+1}$. Substitute in and evaluate.

Comment: What glen_b did was fine but if you want the general discussion of all that material, check out chapters 9, 10 and 11 of this text. https://www.amazon.com/Macroeconomic-Economic-Econometrics-Mathematical-Economics/dp/0126197512#reader_0126197512